# append script text into the end of an asp.net web form page from user control

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, user-controls, webforms

here is what I am doing from user control code behind;

```
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, typeof(Page), 
   "JQuerySearchReminder",
    string.Format("(function() {{ $(function(){{ $('#{0}').val('{1}'); }}); }})();", ddlDestinationTrf.ClientID, srchrmdr["_did"]), 
    true);
```

the script code works fine, nothing wrong there. On the user control I am also using AjaxControlToolkit's `CascadingDropDown` control.

So the problem is that;

this c# code I am using to append the script into page is registered before the `CascadingDropDown` control's script code. this isn't work in this situation Because the dorpdownlist is empty if CascadingDropDown control hasn't done the job.

So guys, let me escape from this lame situation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting `ScriptManager.LoadScriptsBeforeUI` to false. [See here for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.loadscriptsbeforeui.aspx).

Alternatively, couldn't you use jquery's [document.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function to run your javascript code after the document was loaded?

Comment: no, it doesn't work. my aim is not to get the wholse ajax code at the beginning of the page anyway, it is to get this little script code at the end.

Comment: for the document.ready part, I thought this code does that; `$(function(){ });` ?

Comment: @tugberk: when I set `LoadScriptsBeforeUI="false"`, then the script registered with `RegisterStarupScript` is rendered at the very end of the resulting html page (i.e. just before the `</body>` element).